# How to make Erlang client/server connect with arguments/nodes from config?

Tags: erlang, client-server, nodes, distributed

I'm writing a client/server System in Erlang and can't get them to connect. The nodes they should use are stored in config files, which are loaded upon starting them. They also use several distributed data structures. Problem is, I'm first starting the data structure, then the server (works fine) but when I start the client, it doesn't connect to anything and throws an exception.

Server:

```
-module(server).

-export([startServer/0,loopServer/7,node/0,log/0,name/0]).
-compile({no_auto_import,[node/0]}).
-import(werkzeug, [get_config_value/2,lengthSL/1,logging/2,reset_timer/3,get_config_value/2]).
-import(erlang, [append/2]).

log() ->
    erlang:list_to_atom(lists:concat(["Server@", node(),".log"])).

node() ->
    {ok,Config} = file:consult("configs/server.cfg"), 
    {ok, Node} = werkzeug:get_config_value(node,Config),
    Node.

name() ->
    {ok,Config} = file:consult("configs/server.cfg"), 
    {ok, Name} = werkzeug:get_config_value(servername,Config),
    Name.


%%Startet den Server und die darin enthaltene Schleife
startServer() -> 
    {ok,Config} = file:consult("configs/server.cfg"), 
    {ok, Name} = get_config_value(servername,Config),

    %%CMEM initialisieren
    {ok, RemTime} = get_config_value(cmemtime,Config),
    CMEM = cmem:initCMEM(RemTime, log()),

    %%HBQ-Prozess erzeugen
    {ok,HBQName} = get_config_value(hbqname,Config),
    {ok,HBQNode} = get_config_value(node,Config),
    HBQ = {HBQName,HBQNode},

    {ok,Serverzeit} = get_config_value(serverzeit,Config),
    %%Zeitpunkt des Timer übergeben
    {ok, Timer} = timer:send_after(round(RemTime * 1000),Name,delServer),

    %%Prozess registrieren, Serverschleife mit allen Infos starten, plus NNr 1
    ServerPid = spawn(?MODULE, loopServer, [Name,CMEM,HBQ,Timer,Serverzeit,Config,1]),                                                          
    register(Name,ServerPid),

    %%HBQ initialisieren
    HBQ ! {ServerPid, {request,initHBQ}},

    {Config,CMEM,HBQ,ServerPid}.


loopServer(Name,CMEM,HBQ,Timer,Serverzeit,Config,NNr) ->
    receive
        %%Client fragt neue Nachrichten ab, dazu wird aus CMEM die aktuelle NNr für 
        %%den Client angefordert und mit der ClientPID an die HBQ weitergegeben
        {ClientPID,getmessages} ->
            NewTimer = reset_timer(Timer,Serverzeit,delServer),
            ClientNNr = cmem:getClientNNr(CMEM, ClientPID),
            HBQ ! {self(), {request, deliverMSG, ClientNNr, ClientPID}},
            logging(log(), lists:concat(["Server: Nachricht ", NNr, " wurde zugestellt.\n"])),

            loopServer(Name,CMEM,HBQ,NewTimer,Serverzeit,Config,NNr);

        %%Nachricht soll in HBQ verschoben werden
        {dropmessage,[INNr,Msg,TSclientout]} ->
            NewTimer = reset_timer(Timer,Serverzeit,delServer),
            HBQ ! {self(), {request,pushHBQ,[INNr,Msg,TSclientout]}},
            receive
                {reply,ok} ->
                logging(log(), lists:concat(["Server: Nachricht ", INNr, " wurde in HBQ eingefuegt.\n"]))
            end,
            loopServer(Name,CMEM,HBQ,NewTimer,Serverzeit,Config,NNr);

        %%Client fragt naechste NNr ab, diese wird dem Zustand des Server entnommen
        {ClientPID,getmsgid} ->
          NewTimer = reset_timer(Timer,Serverzeit,delServer),
          ClientPID ! {nid, NNr},
          NewNNr = NNr + 1,
          logging(log(), lists:concat(["Server: Nachrichtennumer ", NNr, " an ", erlang:pid_to_list(ClientPID), "gesendet.\n"])),
          loopServer(Name,CMEM,HBQ,NewTimer,Serverzeit,Config,NewNNr);

        %%Server beendet sich selbst und zugleich die HBQ
        delServer ->
            HBQ ! {self(),{request,delHBQ}},
            receive
                {reply,ok} ->
                logging(log(), lists:concat([lists:concat(["Server: Downtime ", werkzeug:timeMilliSecond(), " von ", name() ,"\n"])])),
                ok
            end
    end.
```

Client:

```
-module(client).

-export([startClients/0,loopClient/4,spawnC/1,forLoop/3,mitServerVerbinden/6,configLaden/0]).

-import(werkzeug, [get_config_value/2]).
-import(timer, [apply_after/4]).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Client  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%initClient
startClients() ->
  Config = configLaden(),
  {ok, ClientAnzahl} = werkzeug:get_config_value(clientanzahl, Config),
  {ok, ServerName} = werkzeug:get_config_value(servername, Config),
  {ok, ServerNode} = werkzeug:get_config_value(servernode, Config),
  ServerPid = {ServerName,ServerNode},
forLoop(ClientAnzahl, fun client:spawnC/1, ServerPid).


%%Hilfsfunktion fuer for-Schleife: Zaehlt runter,
%%ruft Funktion auf und gibt Ergebnisse als Liste zurueck
forLoop(Clients, Spawn, SPid) -> forLoop(Clients, Spawn, SPid, []).
forLoop(0, _Spawn, _SPid, ClientListe) -> ClientListe;
forLoop(Clients, Spawn, SPid, ClientListe) ->
  ClientListeNew = ClientListe ++ [Spawn(SPid)],
  ClientsNew = Clients - 1,
forLoop(ClientsNew, Spawn, SPid, ClientListeNew).

%%Neuen ClientProzess erzeugen
spawnC(ServerPid) ->
  Config = configLaden(),
  {ok, Lebenszeit} = werkzeug:get_config_value(lebenszeit, Config),
  {ok, Cookie} = werkzeug:get_config_value(cookie, Config),
  {ok, ServerNode} = werkzeug:get_config_value(servernode, Config),
  {ok, Wartezeit} = werkzeug:get_config_value(wartezeit, Config),
  ClientPid = erlang:spawn(?MODULE, mitServerVerbinden, [ServerPid, [], [], Wartezeit, ServerNode, Cookie]),
  timer:kill_after(Lebenszeit, ClientPid),
ClientPid.

%%mit Server Verbinden
mitServerVerbinden(ServerPid,Datei,NNummern,Wartezeit,ServerNode,Cookie) ->
  erlang:set_cookie(ServerNode,Cookie),
  pong = net_adm:ping(ServerNode),
loopClient(ServerPid,NNummern,Wartezeit,Datei).



%%loopClient
loopClient(ServerPid,NNummern,Wartezeit,Datei) ->

  %%Client wird zum Redakteur
  {NNummernNew, WartezeitNew, DateiNew} = nachrichtenSenden(5,ServerPid,NNummern,Wartezeit,Datei),

  %%Client wird zum Leser
  nachrichtenLesen(false, NNummernNew, ServerPid,DateiNew),

  %%Methode ruft sich selbst wieder auf
  loopClient(ServerPid, NNummernNew, WartezeitNew,DateiNew).


configLaden() ->
  {ok, Config} = file:consult("configs/client.cfg"),
  Config. 




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Redakteur %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%Nachricht soll vergessen werden
nachrichtenSenden(0,ServerPid,NNummern,Wartezeit,Datei) ->

  %%Naechste NNr beim Server anfragen
  ServerPid ! {self(),getmsgid},
  receive 

    %%Server sendet NNr
    {nid,NNr} ->

      %%Logeintrag
  werkzeug:logging(Datei,lists:concat([NNr, "te Nachricht um ", werkzeug:timeMilliSecond(), " vergessen zu senden. ******\n"]))
    end,
  WartezeitNew = wartezeitBerechnen(Wartezeit),

  %%Rückgabewerte: Liste mit Nachrichtennummern fuer leser, neue Wartezeit, Logfile
  {NNummern,WartezeitNew,Datei};




%%Nachrichtennummer anfragen und erhalten, Nachricht schreiben
nachrichtenSenden(NachrichtenVorVergessen,ServerPid,NNummern,Wartezeit,Datei) ->
  Config = configLaden(),
  {ok, ServerNode} = werkzeug:get_config_value(servernode, Config),

  %%Naechste NNr beim Server anfragen
  ServerPid ! {self(),getmsgid},
  receive

    %%Server sendet NNr
    {nid,NNr} ->

     %%Nachricht schreiben
     Nachricht = nachrichtSchreiben(NNr),

      %%NNr zur Liste hinzufuegen fuer Leser
      NNummernNew = NNummern ++[NNr],
      timer:sleep(Wartezeit),

      %%Nachricht an Server senden
      ServerPid ! {dropmessage,[NNr,Nachricht,erlang:now()]},

      %%Logeintrag schreiben
      werkzeug:logging(Datei,lists:concat([Nachricht, " gesendet"])),

    %%Neue Wartezeit berechnen  
    WartezeitNew = wartezeitBerechnen(Wartezeit),

    %%Zaehler dekrementieren  
    NachrichtenVorVergessenNew = NachrichtenVorVergessen -1,

  %%Methode neu aufrufen
  nachrichtenSenden(ServerPid,NNummernNew,WartezeitNew,NachrichtenVorVergessenNew,Datei)
  end.



%%nachrichtSchreiben
nachrichtSchreiben(NNr) ->
  Config = configLaden(),
  {ok, Rechner} = werkzeug:get_config_value(rechner, Config),
  {ok, Praktikumsgruppe} = werkzeug:get_config_value(praktikumsgruppe, Config),
  {ok, Teamnummer} = werkzeug:get_config_value(teamnummer, Config),
lists:concat(["client@",Rechner, "_", Praktikumsgruppe, "_", Teamnummer, ": ", integer_to_list(NNr), "_te Nachricht. Sendezeit: ", werkzeug:timeMilliSecond()]).


%%Hilfsmethode: Intervall darf nicht kleiner als zwei Sekunden werden
minimumTime() -> 2000.

%%Berechnet das neue Zeitintervall, um die Haelfte groesser oder
%%kleiner als die alte Zeit, solange sie groesser gleich 2 Sekunden ist
wartezeitBerechnen(Wartezeit) -> 
    GroesserKleiner = werkzeug:bool_rand(),
  HaelfteZeit = trunc(max(Wartezeit * 0.5, minimumTime())),
  if
    GroesserKleiner ->
      Wartezeit + HaelfteZeit;
    true ->
      max(Wartezeit - HaelfteZeit, minimumTime())
end.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Leser   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


nachrichtenLesen(true,NNummern,ServerPid,Datei) -> ok;

nachrichtenLesen(false,NNummern,ServerPid,Datei) ->
  ServerPid ! {self(),getmessages},
  receive 
    {reply,Message,Terminated} ->
    nachrichtInLogSchreiben(Message,NNummern,Datei),
    nachrichtenLesen(Terminated,NNummern,ServerPid,Datei)
  end.

nachrichtInLogSchreiben([NNr,Msg,TSclientout,TShbqin,TSdlqin,TSdlqout],NNummern,Datei) ->
  Now = erlang:timestamp(),
  DLQInTrue = werkzeug:validTS(TSdlqin),
  DLQOutTrue = werkzeug:validTS(TSdlqout),
  DLQInZukunft = werkzeug:lessTS(Now, TSdlqin),
  DLQOutZukunft = werkzeug:lessTS(Now, TSdlqout),
  MsgVonGleichemClient = msgVonGleichemClient(NNr, Msg, NNummern),
  if
      DLQInTrue and DLQInZukunft ->
      Zeitunterschied = werkzeug:now2stringD(werkzeug:diffTS(TSdlqin, Now)),
      MsgNew = MsgVonGleichemClient ++ ", Zeitunterschied: " ++ Zeitunterschied,
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, MsgNew ++ "\n");
    DLQOutTrue and DLQOutZukunft ->
      Zeitunterschied = werkzeug:now2stringD(werkzeug:diffTS(TSdlqout, Now)),
      MsgNew = MsgVonGleichemClient ++ ", Zeitunterschied: " ++ Zeitunterschied,
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, MsgNew ++ "\n");
    true ->
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, MsgVonGleichemClient ++ "\n")
  end.


msgVonGleichemClient(NNr,Msg,NNummern) ->
    MsgVonGleichemClient = lists:member(NNr, NNummern),
  if
    MsgVonGleichemClient -> Msg ++ "*******";
    true -> Msg
end.
```

Config file for server:

```
{sizedlq,400}.
{servername,'serverpa'}.
{cmemtime,2000}.
{hbqname,'hbqpa'}.
{node,'hbqnode'}.
{serverzeit,50}.
```

Config file for client:

```
{wartezeit,20}.
{lebenszeit,240}.
{pratikumsgruppe,'2'}.
{teamnummer,'02'}.
{servername,'serverpa'}.
{clientanzahl,5}.
{servernode,'servernode'}.
{cookie,pa}.
{rechner,'rechner'}.
```

There are also distributed data strutures which are essentially queues and seem to be working fine:

HBQ:

```
-module(hbq).

-export([startHBQ/0, checkTransfer/6,loophbq/4]).

%%      HBQ !{self(), {request,pushHBQ,[INNr,Msg,TSclientout]}}

startHBQ() ->
  startHBQ("./configs/server.cfg").

%% Used for starting the HBQ with a custom config file


startHBQ(Configfile) ->
        %%Config und Namen auslesen
        Config = loadConfig(Configfile),
    Config = loadConfig(Configfile),
        %%{ok,Config} = file:consult("./config/server.cfg"),
        {ok,HBQName} = werkzeug:get_config_value(hbqname,Config),

        %%Prozess der HBQ starten
        HBQPid = spawn(?MODULE,loophbq,[[],[],Config, 1]),

        %%Prozess registrieren
        register(HBQName,HBQPid),
        HBQPid.



loophbq(HBQ,DLQ,Config,CurrNumber) ->
    receive 
        %%initialisere HBQ und DLQ, sendet ok an Server
        {ServerPid,{request,initHBQ}} ->
            HBQList = [],
            Log = log(Config,["HBQ>>> initialisiert worden von ", ServerPid, ".\n"]),
            {ok,DLQSize} = werkzeug:get_config_file(sizedlq,Config),
            DLQ = dlq:initDLQ(DLQSize,Log),
            ServerPid ! {reply,ok},
            loophbq(HBQList, DLQ ,Config, CurrNumber);      

        %%fuegt der Msg einen Zeitstempel hinzu, fuegt sie in HBQ ein, sendet ok
        {ServerPid,{request,pushHBQ,[NNr,Msg,TSclientout]}} ->  
            TShbqin = werkzeug:timeMillliSecond(),
            NewMessage = {NNr,lists:concat(Msg,["HBQ in: ",TShbqin])},
            Log = log(Config,["HBQ>>> Nachricht ",NNr, "in HBQ eingefügt.\n"]),
            NewHBQ = [HBQ|NewMessage],
            lists:sort(fun({A,_},{B,_}) -> A=<B end),       
            checkTransfer(NewHBQ, CurrNumber, Config, DLQ,TSclientout,TShbqin),
            ServerPid ! {reply,ok}, 
            loophbq(NewHBQ, DLQ ,Config, CurrNumber);

        %%DLQ soll über HBQ Nachricht an Client senden
        {ServerPid,{request,deliverMSG,NNr,ToClient}} ->
            {ok, HBQName} = werkzeug:get_config_value(hbqname, Config),
            Log = lists:concat(["HB-DLQ@", HBQName, ".log"]),
            Datei = erlang:list_to_atom(Log),
            log(Config, ["HBQ>>> dlq:delivermsg", NNr, pid_to_list(ToClient), "\n"]),
            NNrDLQ = dlq:deliverMSG(NNr, ToClient, DLQ, Datei),
            ServerPid ! {reply, NNrDLQ},
            loophbq(HBQ, DLQ ,Config, CurrNumber);

        %%Terminiert Prozess der DLQ
        {ServerPid,{request,delHBQ}} ->
            ServerPid ! {reply,ok},
            ok
      end.


%%CheckTransfer
checkTransfer(HBQ, Number, Config, [DLQ,Size],TSclientout,TShbqin) -> 
    Datei = log(Config, ["HBQ>>> Nachricht Nr ", Number, " wird in DLQ uebertragen\n"]),
    FoundMatch = lists:keyfind(Number, 1, HBQ),
    if  FoundMatch =:= false ->
        if(length(HBQ)>Size*0.667) -> 
        [{MinNNr,_}|_] = HBQ,
        %wegen sort ist immer die kleinste NNr vorne in der Liste 
        NewMessage = {MinNNr-1,lists:concat(["Weiß noch nicht was hier reinsoll: ",werkzeug:timeMilliSecond()])},
        NewHBQ = lists:append([{MinNNr-1,NewMessage}], HBQ),
        log(Config,["HBQ>>> Fehlernachricht fuer Nachrichten ",Number," bis",MinNNr-1, " generiert.\n"]),
        NewNumber = MinNNr-1,
        checkTransfer(NewHBQ, NewNumber, Config,[DLQ,Size],TSclientout,TShbqin);
        true -> ok
        end;
    true ->
        {MatchNr,Msg} = FoundMatch,
        dlq:push2DLQ([MatchNr, Msg, TSclientout, TShbqin], DLQ, Datei),
        lists:delete(FoundMatch, HBQ),
        checkTransfer(HBQ, Number+1, Config,[DLQ,Size],TSclientout,TShbqin)
end.



log(Config,Message) -> 
    {ok,HBQNode} = werkzeug:get_config_value(node,Config),
    DateiName = lists:concat(["HB-DLQ@", HBQNode,".log"]),
    Datei = erlang:list_to_atom(DateiName),
    werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(Message)),
    Datei.

%%Dummy-Nachrichten schreiben um Lücken in der HBQ zu füllen wenn sie kritische Größe erreicht

%%Methode um zu prüfen, ob Nachrichten in DLQ geschoben werden können, das dann auch machen
loadConfig(Configfile) ->
  {ok, Config} = file:consult(Configfile),
Config.
```

DLQ:

```
-module(dlq).

-export([initDLQ/2, delDLQ/1, expectedNr/1, push2DLQ/3, deliverMSG/4]).

%%Initialisiert DLQ mit Kapazitaet Size, Log in Datei
initDLQ(Size, Datei) -> 
werkzeug:logging(Datei,lists:concat(["DLQ>>> intitialisiert worden mit Groesse ",Size,".\n"])),
[[],Size].

%%Loescht DLQ
delDLQ(_Queue) -> ok.

%%Liefert NNr die als naechstes in DLQ gespeichert werden kann
%%expectedNr(Queue)
expectedNr([[], _Size]) -> 1;
expectedNr([[[NNr, _Msg, _TSclientout, _TShbqin, _TSdlqin] | _Rest], _Size]) -> NNr + 1.

%%Speichert Nachricht in DLQ, fuegt Zeitstempel hinzu, Rueckgabe: Modifizierte DLQ
%%push2DLQ([NNr, Msg, TSclientout, TShbqin], Queue, Datei)
%%Fehlt noch: Abfrage, ob das die passende Nummer ist!

push2DLQ([NNr, Msg, TSclientout, TShbqin], [DLQ,Size], Datei) ->
  if
    length(DLQ) < Size ->
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> Nachricht ", NNr, " in DLQ eingefügt.\n"])),
      [[[NNr, Msg, TSclientout, TShbqin, erlang:now()] | DLQ], Size];
    length(DLQ) =:= Size ->
      [LastNNr, _Msg, _TSclientout, _TShbqin, _TSdlqin] = lists:last(DLQ),
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> Nachricht ", LastNNr, " aus DLQ entfernt.\n"])),
      werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> Nachricht ", NNr, " in DLQ eingefügt.\n"])),
      [[[NNr, Msg, TSclientout, TShbqin, erlang:now()] | lists:droplast(DLQ)], Size]
end.

%%Sendet Nachricht an Leser-Client
deliverMSG(MSGNr, ClientPID, Queue, Datei) ->

  %%Aendern: MSGNer = -1, flag am Ende der Reply (siehe zeile 42)
    [{NewestNr,Msg}|Rest] = Queue,
    if MSGNr > NewestNr ->
           DummyMessage = {-1,lists:concat(["DLQ in: ",werkzeug:timeMilliSecond()])}, %% -1 Flag
            werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> DummyNachricht fuer ",MSGNr," an Client ",ClientPID, " ausgeliefert.\n"])),
            ClientPID ! {reply,Msg,true}
    end,    
%%%%%%Ab hier noch aendern bzgl Flag
        FoundMatch = lists:keyfind(MSGNr, 1, Queue),
        if
          FoundMatch =:= false -> 
            deliverMSG(MSGNr+1, ClientPID, Queue, Datei),
         if 
       MSGNr =:= NewestNr ->
            {Number,Msg} = FoundMatch,
            NewMessage = {Number,lists:concat(Msg,["DLQ in: ",werkzeug:timeMilliSecond()],-1)},
            werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> Nachricht ", Number, " an Client ",ClientPID, " ausgeliefert.\n"])),
            ClientPID ! {reply,Msg,false};
        true ->
        {Number,Msg} = FoundMatch,
            NewMessage = {Number,lists:concat(Msg,["DLQ in: ",werkzeug:timeMilliSecond()],0)},
            werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["DLQ>>> Nachricht ", Number, " an Client ",ClientPID, " ausgeliefert.\n"])),
            ClientPID ! {reply,Msg,false}
         end;
     true ->
        ok
        end.
```

CMEM:

```
-module(cmem).

-export([initCMEM/2, delCMEM/1, updateClient/4, getClientNNr/2]).

-import(werkzeug, [get_config_value/2,lengthSL/1,logging/2,reset_timer/3,get_config_value/2,getUTC/0]).

%%Initialisiert CMEM
initCMEM(RemTime, Datei) -> werkzeug:logging(Datei, lists:concat(["CMEM>>> initialisiert mit  ", RemTime, " Sekunden\n"])),
  [[], RemTime].

%%Loescht CMEM
delCMEM(_CMEM) -> ok.

%%Speichert/aktualisiert Client und NNr im CMEM, 
updateClient([CMEM, RemTime], ClientID, NNr, Datei) -> 
  ClientTS = getUTC(),
  logging(Datei, lists:concat(["CMEM>>> Client ", ClientID, " wird aktualisiert.\n"])),
  [lists:keystore(ClientID, 1, CMEM, {ClientID, NNr, ClientTS}), RemTime].

%%Gibt naechste vom Client erwartete NNr zurueck
%%Es wird geprueft ob Client in der Liste steht und dann
%%mit diesem Wissen eine Hilfsfunktion aufgerufen
getClientNNr([CMEM, RemTime], ClientID) ->
  ClientBekannt = lists:keymember(ClientID, 1, CMEM),
  isClientKnown([CMEM, RemTime], ClientID, ClientBekannt).

%%Client ist nicht bekannt: Naechste NNr = 1
isClientKnown(_CMEM, _ClientID, false) -> 1;

%% Der Client ist bekannt.
%%Zeit noch nicht abgelaufen: Gibt naechste Nummer aus
%%Zeit abgelaufen: Naechste NNr = 1
isClientKnown([CMEM, RemTime], ClientID, true) ->
  {ClientID, NNr, ClientTS} = lists:keyfind(ClientID, 1, CMEM),
  RemainingTime = ClientTS + RemTime,
  Now = getUTC(),
  if
    RemainingTime >= Now -> NNr + 1;
    true -> 1
end.
```

The client is supposed to contact the server sending it a message, the server puts it in data structures which send it back to the client under the right circumstances.
The problem is, when I compile them, the start the HBQ, then the server and then the client, I get

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Apr-2017::10:25:46 ===
Error in process <0.104.0> with exit value: {distribution_not_started,[{auth,set_cookie,2,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,119}]},{client,mitServerVerbinden,6,[{file,"client.erl"},{line,42}]}]}
```

So apparently there is an issue with the client not connecting to the server. This is my first time working with Erlang and distributed systems, so I have no idea what is going on.

Is it not enough to put the nodes and cookie into the configs and tell the components of the system to look there?

Answer (score 0):

The error `distribution_not_started` is returned by the auth module when the erlang VM calling it does not have a name. Ensure that a `-sname` or `-name` flag is passed when starting erlang e.g.:

```
erl -sname test
```